# List of Integers in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

```
public Class Animal
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public ICollection<int> OwnerIds{ get; set; }
}
```

Animal class contains a list of int (ownerIds).

Entity framework is not creating a table for OwnerIds, how can i map this??

Comment: EF can map only collections of related entities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add second entity Owner, only property is int ID, add a relationship/association between them.